# javascript or jquery : replace last string with condition

Tags: jquery, regex, cut

**Correct sentences**
Your flight is confirmed. Seat is confirmed.
pending airline approval.
The airline will assign seats at check-in.
The seat you requested was not available.

**Wrong sentences**
*Your flight is confirmed. Seat is confirmed. You may

pending airline approval. You may

The airline will assign seats at check-in or you may

The seat you requested was not available. The airline has assigned a different  You may*

These are the possible sentences. I need to cut the last part (You may / or you may) so that it end with the last dot.
How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the follow javascript code on every line to remove the text.

Example:

```
var string = "Your flight is confirmed. Seat is confirmed. You may";

string.replace(/((or)* you may)$/i, "");
```

This will get rid of "You may" or "or you may"

Answer (score 1):

My idea was the same than @AlexCheuk AlexCheuk
Use a short regexp such as

```
replace(/((or)* you may)$/i, "")
```

Or use this regexp if you want to replace all text at once:

```
replace(/((or)* you may)/gi, "")
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/pvU8T/16/)

Answer (score 0):

You use subtring() because The substring() method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this replace in java script to add your full stop at the end too.

```
string.replace(/((or)*\.+ you may)$/i, ".");
```

This will get rid of "You may" or "or you may"